# Place features along a line with internal mileage

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I have several polyline segments representing railway lines, and each segment (`Railway_1`, `Railway_2` etc.) has its own internal mileage (`Km_start` and `Km_end`).

From a separate table, I have features to draw along this line. The table contains `Km_start` and `Km_end` attributes for each feature, as well as the side of the line to place them (left or right when looking towards increasing mileage).

How can I use these attributes to draw the features along the line? I would prefer to draw them as lines, but points would also be acceptable. I am working in ArcGIS Pro, and Python is also available to manipulate the data.

Attribute table for polylines (Example):

| Railway | Km_start | Km_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Railway_1 | 101.2 | 150.1 |
| Railway_1 | 150.1 | 172.13 |
| Railway_2 | 10.2 | 40.9 |
| Railway_2 | 40.9 | 120.5 |

Attribute table for features to be drawn (Example):

| Railway | Km_start | Km_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Railway_1 | 101.34 | 101.35 |
| Railway_1 | 102.77 | 102.77 |
| Railway_2 | 15.01 | 15.06 |

Comment: Are the railway's start and end values literally lengths or are they some sort of measured distance that someone added to the attributes? This sounds like it might be a route problem, have you looked into routes?